# Dragging and dropping an object causes Firefox 33.1 to jump to an invalid URL

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, firefox

EDITED: I didn't make this clear enough before...

I am developing an application using jQuery and AngularJS. Part of the app involves dragging a element and dropping it onto another. The problem is that when I srop the element, Firefox tries to load a new URL, which it tells me is invalid.

I have managed to replicate the problem in Plunker:
 http://plnkr.co/edit/PGYH67vKp2WoT7xbZTcs?p=preview

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var dragElement = document.getElementById("dragElement");
  dragElement.addEventListener("dragstart", dragstart);

  var dropBox = document.getElementById("dropBox");
  dropBox.addEventListener("drop", drop);
  dropBox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover);


  function dragstart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.attributes["data-drag"].value);
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copyMove";
  }

  function dragover(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function drop(e) {
    alert("dropped");
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><!-- Title here --></title>
    <link data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jqueryui" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div id="dragElement" draggable="true" data-drag="Banana Cake">
    Drag me to the red box in Firefox
</div>

<div id="dropBox"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

If you go to the bottom of the javascript to the function drop(e) and then comment out the alert, the browser tries to go somewhere else. Leave the alert and the page stays put.

This only happens in Firefox. Chrome, IE and Opera work fine. Safari won't let me drop, but that's a different story.

Many thanks!

Craig

Comment: I have tried various versions of jQuery and Angular. No difference.

Comment: Here's an update! If I add a real URL to the data-drag attribute, Firefox will go there e.g. data-drag="http://www.orf.at"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the Profiler in Chrome - this could give you some insight into where the request is being generated. However, it sounds like a deep seated Firefox issue to me.

EDIT: OK got it....

You need to add e.preventDefault(); to the drop function as well as the dragover.

Comment: Putting a breakpoint on the console.log line is interesting. The script stops twice there. The first time runs through ok, the second time it goes off to the new URL. In Chrome, it only stops at the line once.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:
I first used setData/getData("something", "somethingelse"), which worked perfectly (in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer...), and then replaced "something" by "text". After that, I had the same problem you described. Using event.preventDefault() in the ondrop callback (not only in the ondragover callback!) helped me, as Jon Arnott suggested.